# Is there a standard ImageViewer on Android?

Tags: android, image, viewer

There are some applications out there, that use a kind of standard way for showing images to the user. There is one i specially like, is the Facebook one. Facebook presents images to the user in full screen mode, with a black background. If user clicks on the image, there appears a left and/or right arrow to move to next/previous image in the album. You also have zoom controls enabled. Quite powerful and nice.

Android Market uses same arrows for switching between views, but zoom controls are not enabled. They're probably using a ImageSwitcher for that.

Does somebody know if there is a similar standard control in Android for that?. Something more like Facebook uses?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is a Gallery class in Android. Check it out. There is a Gallery demo in the API demos as well....

Also, there is no standard gallery app across all Android phones, however, you could ask your users to download the com.cooliris.media app which is the exact code for the stock android gallery.

Finally, you could pass your users to the gallery (assuming they have cooliris installed) using an Intent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!. However, that's not exactly what i was looking for. I was thinking more on a ImageViewer view where the user can zoom in/out and go to the next picture through some arrows on left and right side. Facebook as an example, is using that approach

Answer (score 0):

Check [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) library by Chris Banes.